# Setting up Asterisk IVR on out call

Tags: asterisk, ivr, agi

I am making an IVR system on asterisk on out going calls create an agi and working fine as expected, now issue is i am not able to do one thing that when i make a call from AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface) and **receiver answer the call and ivr starts** and ask about menu which is i am not able to do need help.

I have to run IVR after call answered.

Using Asterisk 11.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have read any asterisks book. Just to understand how to create dialplan for your ivr.

Comment: I have tried many and i can able to make incoming call but facing problems in incoming call originated via my script.

Comment: Read this: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out . Unfortanly based on info you provided no other help posible. Need more data.